# Very low wiper resistance Digital Pots - Anyone know of any?

Tags: digital-potentiometer

I am trying to find a 1k linear digital pot which has a very low (preferably 0) wiper resistance. Any interface would be ok (apart from just up/down).

I found this article: http://electronicdesign.com/components/active-cancellation-pots-wiper- resistance 
which could be a way around the issue.

What I am trying to do, is substitute the 1k pot in the classic fuzz circuit

http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/fuzzface/fftech.htm

with a digitally controlled one, and it needs to pretty much go down to 0 Ohm to get the full fuzz effect. I am not sure if the above 'trick' may interfere the fuzz's simple circuit which is extremely sensitive.

Does anyone have any suggestions, feedback or alternative idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You do know that "real" potentiometers *also* have non-zero wiper resistance, right?

Comment: yes but they tend to be quite low. around 1-2 Ohm or less. All the digital ones I've seen seem to be at least 50+ Ohm.
I would be fine with 1-2 even 5 ohms...

Comment: How much resolution do you need? What step size? How many steps?

Comment: I was hoping for 128 steps, which would map nicely to MIDI controller messages.

Answer (score 4):

You will likely not find such a part because there will always be some kind of electrical switch in a digital potentiometer, and these always have some built-in resistance.

You can however compensate the resistance. You've already linked one article that shows it, but you can improve upon that.

A single OpAmp and three resistors can work as a negative resistor. If you tune the negative resistance to your wiper resistance you end up with near perfect compensation.

[Wikipedia Article on Negative Impendance Converters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_impedance_converter)

For your application there is even a article on the web that does exactly what you need:

[Negative Resistance Nulls Potentiometer's Wiper Resistance](http://electronicdesign.com/components/negative-resistance-nulls-potentiometers-wiper-resistance)